# How to stop or start individual database in PostgreSQL 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We have multiple Databases created in our Postgres Instance. For maintenance, we want to bring down only one particular DB at a time while others are functional. Is there a way?

Comment: That's not possible. If you start an instance all databases are "started" as well.

Comment: You can disallow connections via `ALTER database`, or (selectively) disallow *new* connections via pg_hba.conf.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
pg_ctl -D /opt/path/postgres_database stop -m fast
```